# Position elements under each other

Tags: css, position

I have two elements I want to put next to each other, and three elements I want to put below the first two, like this:

Element 1 Element 2

Element 3 Element 4 Element 5

These are text elements actually, and no matter how long the text might be, I want them to still stay in that position. How do I do this without using **&nbsp** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `<div>` tags to create two different containers.

```
<div>
  Element 1 Element 2
</div>

<div>
  Element 3 Element 4 Element 5
</div>
```

Comment: This worked great :) I feel kinda stupid though, haven't done any work on either html nor css in a few years!

Answer (score 5):

If it's a text use `<br>` for this. Write like this:

```
Element 1 Element 2 <br>Element 3 Element 4 Element 5
```

& if it's HTML elements. Write like this:

**HTML**

```
<div>element1</div>
<div>element2</div>
<div class="ele3">element3</div>
<div>element4</div>
<div>element4</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
}
.ele3{
  clear:both;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/K9Smv/

Answer (score 2):

```
<div>
    element1
    element2
</div>

<div class="new_line">
    element3
    element4
    element5
</div>

<div class="new_line">
    element6
    element7
    element8
    element9
</div>

div{
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
}
.new_line{
  clear:both;
}
```